# Altium : How to design a width rule for a subset of a net?

Tags: altium, design-rules

On my current design, I want to set a width rule for some nets which provide power in order to get them fatter. I set a net class on the net,set a rule and it works pretty well.

Now, this net is also used as an input on a ADC pin of a microcontroler. The first thing is that I don't need a fat connector for this purpose, the second is that there's no way to connect a fat line to only one pin of the microcontroler.

Is there a way to exclude a part of the net class from the rule ? Or a specific rule but based on which information ?

Here are two screenshots for illustration purposes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three approaches:

- Use a net-tie: A net tie will create two distinct nets (each has its own name) but they are actually joined. Information on how to create & use a net tie can be found [here - Altium - Using Net Ties to Meet PCB Design Requirements](https://resources.altium.com/p/using-net-ties-to-meet-pcb-design-requirements).
- Use a 0R resistor. Again, this will create an additional net.
- Scope your rules so that they target only specific areas. You can either target your rule to only apply within a specific room or within specific coordinates on your board.

Comment: Would a Neck-Down rule be of any help here? http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADRR/PCB_Dlg-SMDNeckDownRule_Frame((SMD+Neck-Down))_AD

Comment: No, the Neck-Down rule only applies to pad entries, not to tracks themselves. You will need to scope the Routing -> Width rule to your desired values. Even if you set up a Neck-Down rule you would still get the width rule violations.

Comment: Net ties, really interesting. Would be cool to be able to resize each of them  directly on the PCB...

Comment: That would be too easy ;-). Yet, experience has shown that for 90% of the cases where you need them, basically 3 or 4 different sizes are enough.